# Joomla 3.9 - Home Page Disappeared When I published twice a custom Module Developed by me

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I developed a joomla module, it was working fine. When it was published once but when i published it again on same page, then home page gone and i got 500 error, and if I tried to unpublished one module both got unpublished.

How to resolve that issue. As a guess i think i should create a dynamic id with every module. but i dont know how to do that in joomla.

This code is making problems.

```
function group_by_key($array) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $sub) {
        foreach ($sub as $k => $v) {
            $result[$k][] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$features_list = array(
    $features_list1 = group_by_key($features[0]),
    $features_list2 = group_by_key($features[1]),
    $features_list3 = group_by_key($features[2]),
    $features_list4 = group_by_key($features[3]),
);
```

Because i am getting below error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare group_by_key() (previously declared in E:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\do\modules\mod_xp_comparison\tmpl\default.php:31) in E:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\do\modules\mod_xp_comparison\tmpl\default.php on line 40
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me.  Do you know that there is [joomla.se] Stack Exchange?

Comment: check now i explained more.

Comment: ...personally, I'd rather you posted at JSE so that that community continues to receive fresh questions and so you receive support from a dedicated audience.  You have 200 points here, so when you start your JSE account, you will start with 101 rep and privileges.

Comment: Why do you need a duplicate custom module?

Comment: basically i want to publish this module twice on same page but this  group_by_key is making problem to repeat this module.

Comment: Can you make the first module "the master", then any additional copies of the module will not have function declatations, but use "the master's" functions? I don't think I would go for such a workaround but maybe you just need a quick patch.

Comment: lets see if i got solution. otherwise i will have to wait for your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187258/discussion-between-hassan-raza-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it this way:

```
if (!function_exists('group_by_key')) {
    function group_by_key($array) {
        $result = array();

        foreach ($array as $sub) {
            foreach ($sub as $k => $v) {
                $result[$k][] = $v;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$features_list = array(
    $features_list1 = group_by_key($features[0]),
    $features_list2 = group_by_key($features[1]),
    $features_list3 = group_by_key($features[2]),
    $features_list4 = group_by_key($features[3]),
);
```

The reason of the above is that you cannot include (or declare) the same function twice. So if it is already defined in a Global scope in your `default.php` for example then it's just causing a conflict. Thus if you are not sure, then you have to use that function inside an `if (!function_exists('any_function_name')) { ...// function ... }` condition statement.

Comment: Code only answers are helpful, but code plus an explanation is even better, consider added some text explaining what you change and why that worked.

Comment: @Elin - Thanks for the note, I'll give a short explanation to that a bit later

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow standard Joomla practices, instead of placing custom functions in the layout, create a helper class (`helper.php`):

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class ModXpComparisonHelper
{
    public static function group_by_key($array)
    {
        $result = array();

        foreach ($array as $sub)
        {
            foreach ($sub as $k => $v)
            {
                $result[$k][] = $v;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Include the helper in main module file (`mod_xp_comparison.php`):

```
JLoader::register('ModXpComparisonHelper', __DIR__ . '/helper.php');
```

And then call the function when needed:

```
$features_list = array(
    $features_list1 = ModXpComparisonHelper::group_by_key($features[0]),
    $features_list2 = ModXpComparisonHelper::group_by_key($features[1]),
    $features_list3 = ModXpComparisonHelper::group_by_key($features[2]),
    $features_list4 = ModXpComparisonHelper::group_by_key($features[3]),
);
```